# How to load data from file in one stateful class and use it in another stateful class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. I have a dart file "CreateDatabase.dart" which should fetch data from a csv file and store in a variable. In another file, "main.dart", I want to access this variable to use the fetched data. 
The "CreateDatabase.dart" file looks like this:

```dart
class CreateDatabase extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return CreateDatabaseState();
  }
}

class CreateDatabaseState extends State<CreateDatabase> {
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    fetchVenueDatabase();

  }
  List<List<dynamic>> venueDB;
  List<Buildings> buildings;

  List<Buildings> getBuildings(){
    return this.buildings;
  }

  Future<String> _loadVenueDatabase() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/VenueDatabase.csv');
  }

  Future<List<List<dynamic>>> loadVenuedatabase() async {
    String data = await _loadVenueDatabase();
    List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues = const CsvToListConverter().convert(data);
    return rowsAsListOfValues;
  }

 fetchVenueDatabase() async{
    venueDB = await loadVenuedatabase();
    ......
    //manipulating venueDB and storing its value in this.buildings
    ......
    this.buildings = buildings;
 }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And the main.dart file looks like this:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  static List<Buildings> allBuildings;

  @override
  void initState() {            //Initial State of the app
    super.initState();
    CreateDatabaseState cr = CreateDatabaseState();
    allBuildings = cr.getBuildings();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ....
  }
}
```

But the getter method in main,

```dart
allBuildings= cr.getBuildings();
```

is always returning null. Where am I wrong?

Comment: That's an anti-pattern. You shouldn't do that. Instead, you should have one stateful widget that stores the data, which is an ancestor of all widgets which need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldnt use a Widget for that. Just create a normal class and define your methods there.

```
class Database {
}
  List<List<dynamic>> venueDB;
  List<Buildings> buildings;

  List<Buildings> getBuildings(){
    return this.buildings;
  }

  Future<String> _loadVenueDatabase() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/VenueDatabase.csv');
  }

  Future<List<List<dynamic>>> loadVenuedatabase() async {
    String data = await _loadVenueDatabase();
    List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues = const CsvToListConverter().convert(data);
    return rowsAsListOfValues;
  }

 fetchVenueDatabase() async{
    venueDB = await loadVenuedatabase();
    ......
    //manipulating venueDB and storing its value in this.buildings
    ......
    this.buildings = buildings;
 }
}
```

Then in your main class just plain and simple.

```
Database db = Database();
allBuildings = db.getBuildings();
```

Then you need to load the venues before db.getBuildings() or do some async stuff. But this should be easy to do. One option would be to make the main() method async and await for some kind of dataLoading. You could make the venueDB List static so that it holds the data independent of the Database object.

This way you can call: Database.fetchVenueData() which then must use the static List and be of course static itself.

```
Future main() async {
   await Database.fetchVenueData();
   runApp(MyApp());
}
```

and the modified Database class:

```
 static List<List<dynamic>> venueDB;

 static Future<void> fetchVenueDatabase() async{
    venueDB = await loadVenuedatabase();
    ......
    //manipulating venueDB and storing its value in this.buildings
    ......
    Database.buildings = buildings;
 }
```

But there are many more options.

**Disclaimer**: I have not compiled that code. So perhaps there is a missing piece or something but you should get the idea.

**Disclaimer2**: static variables are kind of bad. So use them wisely. They wont get garbage collected but i assume this CSV data should reside in memory anyway as long as your app is running. If this shouldnt be the case, there are far better options.